# Cannot see foreign key values in the template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

This is my 2nd week learning Django. I'm trying to get comfortable with Django Template Language. I'm trying to make an Inventory app with 4 models. The views for them are class-based.

The templates for Ingredient and Menu work as expected. However, I'm struggling with trying to loop through values from the Purchase model which has a foreign key field 'menu_item'. The template is not showing anything from the for loop. I've referred numerous articles here to find most of them use function-based views. I've tried using {% for purchase in purchase_set %}, {% for purchase in purchase_set.all %}. I know the object to iterate over is a query-set. I cannot figure out what to do?

MODELS.PY

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    Pounds = 'lbs'
    Ounces = 'oz'
    Grams = 'gms'
    Eggs = 'eggs'
    Piece = 'piece'
    Litre = 'litre'
    unit_choices = [(Pounds, 'lbs'),
                    (Ounces, 'ounces'),
                    (Grams, 'grams'),
                    (Eggs, 'eggs'),
                    (Piece, 'piece'),
                    (Litre, 'litre')]
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    unit_price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=unit_choices)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class RecipeRequirement(models.Model):
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.menu_item.title

class Purchase(models.Model):
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.menu_item.title
```

VIEWS.PY:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Ingredient, MenuItem, RecipeRequirement, Purchase
from django.views.generic import ListView

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'inventory/home.html')

class IngredientView(ListView):
    model = Ingredient
    template_name = 'inventory/ingredients.html'

class PurchaseView(ListView):
    model = Purchase
    template_name = 'inventory/purchases.html'

class MenuView(ListView):
    model = MenuItem
    template_name = 'inventory/menu.html'
```

PURCHASES.HTML

```
<h3>This is purchases page.</h3>
{% block content %}
<table>
{% for purchase in purchase_set.all %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ purchase.title }}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `title` field you are trying to show is in `MenuItem` model that is used as foreignkey in `Purchase` model with `menu_item` field. ListView class returns to context yours purchases in `object_list` key. So in Your purchases.html template:

```
<h3>This is purchases page.</h3>
{% block content %}
<table>
{% for purchase in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ purchase.menu_item.title }}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

PS. This `purchase_set' is referring to reverse relationship. So if you would want to show all purchases of MenuItem you would do:

```
{% for item in menuitems %}
  <h1>{{ item }}</h1>
   {% for purchase in item.purchase_set.all %}
      <p>{{ purchase.timestamp }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I changed the iterable to "object_list" and tried to reference the value with "purchase.menu_item.title". Nothing has changed. I also restarted the Django server.

Comment: Podsiadlo. Also, I tried the nested for loop. Same result.

Comment: this nested forloop is for MenuView (but you need to change key names). For Purchases try to debug: Do you have any purchase objects in db? try {{ object_list }} in template does it shows anything?  and try with purchase_list instead of object_list it confuses me some times because i mostly use FBV

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thanks a lot...